# Is it possible to speed up footage by more than 4x in Sony Vegas Movie Studio?

Tags: video-editor, vegas-pro

I have set the clip playback speed to 4.000 (to run at 4x the orginial speed) as show below.

[image]

This is as high as the software allows. I would like to go further, perhaps as much as 12x as fast.

I am aware that the Pro version of this software includes the ability to use 'velocity envelopes' to increase the speed.

Answer (score 4):

The only workaround I know of is to:

1. Speed up the footage by the desired amount (in this case 4X)
2. Render the clip.
3. Import the clip
4. Repeat steps 1-3 until satisfied.

This isn't ideal as repetitively rendering the clip repeatedly is fairly time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

you just right clic the clip, select insert / remove embelop ,  velocity ,  then rise up that green line that appears on your clip.

Comment: That won't work, since Vegas Movie Studio doesn't have envelopes like Vegas Pro.